# Detect outliers in a vector and draw a heat map

Tags: r

How can I detect outliers in a vector?

For example, I have the following vectors

```
color<-c("green","green","green","green","green","red","blue")
size<-c("big","small","big","big","big","small","medium")
```

for each vector I want to detect outliers and drawn an heat map

- `color` outliers are in positions 6 and 7
- `size` outliers are in    positions 2,6,7

Comment: What is an outlier accourding to your definition? Everything that is *not* the most common value? The least common value? Something inbetween (what?)?

Comment: @DavidArenburg what's up with the ש in the title?

Comment: ... to the OP: what kind of a heatmap?  Can you explain more/show an example?

Comment: @BenBolker sorry, Hebrew stuff :s

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
color <- c("green","green","green","green","green","red","blue")
tt <- table(color)
names(tt)[tt<2]   ## values with frequency < 2
## 'blue', 'red'
ptt <- prop.table(tt)
names(ptt)[ptt<0.2]  ## values with frequency < 20%
## 'blue', 'red'
```